# Python: Conditional Arithmetic on pandas columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My data looks like:

```
df = 
contact_id  date    answer
         1  1-May   9.00-10.00
         1  2-May   9.00-10.00
         1  3-May   11.00-12.00
         1  4-May   14.00-15.00
         1  5-May   10.00-11.00
         2  2-May   9.00-10.00
         2  3-May   9.00-10.00
         3  1-May   14.00-15.00
         3  2-May   10.00-11.00
```

**I want the data to look like**:

```
df = 
    contact_id   date   9.00-10.00  10.00-11.00 11.00-12.00 14.00-15.00  answer
             1  1-May            0            0            0          0  9.00-10.00
             1  2-May            1            0            0          0  9.00-10.00
             1  3-May            2            0            0          0  11.00-12.00
             1  4-May            2            0            1          0  14.00-15.00
             1  5-May            2            0            1          1  10.00-11.00
             2  2-May            0            0            0          0  9.00-10.00
             2  3-May            1            0            0          0  9.00-10.00
             3  1-May            0            0            0          0  14.00-15.00
             3  2-May            0            0            0          1  10.00-11.00
```

**[UPDATE]**
So I got some logic which seems to be working but not quite exactly. It would be great if you could suggest me something here. Following is my code:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df["answer"])],1)
df1["target"] = df1["answer"]
df1.drop("answer", inplace=True, axis=1)

tar_list =  df1["target"].unique().tolist()

def arith(x):

NinetoTenCounter = 0
EleventoTwelveCounter = 0
TwotoThreeCounter = 0
TentoElevenCounter = 0

for i in range(len(x["target"])):
    print(i)
    if x.iloc[i, -1] == "9.00-10.00":
        NinetoTenCounter += 1
        x.loc[i, '9.00-10.00'] = NinetoTenCounter - 1
        x.loc[i, '10.00-11.00'] = TentoElevenCounter
        x.loc[i, '11.00-12.00'] = EleventoTwelveCounter
        x.loc[i, '14.00-15.00'] = TwotoThreeCounter

    elif x.iloc[i,-1] == "11.00-12.00":
        EleventoTwelveCounter += 1
        x.loc[i, '9.00-10.00'] = NinetoTenCounter 
        x.loc[i, '10.00-11.00'] = TentoElevenCounter
        x.loc[i, '11.00-12.00'] = EleventoTwelveCounter - 1
        x.loc[i, '14.00-15.00'] = TwotoThreeCounter

    elif x.iloc[i,-1] == "14.00-15.00":
        TwotoThreeCounter += 1
        x.loc[i, '9.00-10.00'] = NinetoTenCounter 
        x.loc[i, '10.00-11.00'] = TentoElevenCounter 
        x.loc[i, '11.00-12.00'] = EleventoTwelveCounter 
        x.loc[i, '14.00-15.00'] = TwotoThreeCounter - 1

    else:
        TentoElevenCounter += 1
        x.loc[i, '9.00-10.00'] = NinetoTenCounter 
        x.loc[i, '10.00-11.00'] = TentoElevenCounter - 1
        x.loc[i, '11.00-12.00'] = EleventoTwelveCounter 
        x.loc[i, '14.00-15.00'] = TwotoThreeCounter

return x

df1_arith = df1.groupby("contact_id").apply(arith)
```

And the output I am getting is following:

```
              contact_id   date  10.00-11.00  11.00-12.00  14.00-15.00  \
contact_id                                                               
1          0         1.0  1-may          0.0          0.0          0.0   
           1         1.0  2-may          0.0          0.0          0.0   
           2         1.0  3-may          0.0          0.0          0.0   
           3         1.0  4-may          0.0          1.0          0.0   
           4         1.0  5-may          0.0          1.0          1.0   
2          5         2.0  2-may          0.0          0.0          0.0   
           6         2.0  3-may          0.0          0.0          0.0   
           0         NaN    NaN          0.0          0.0          0.0   
           1         NaN    NaN          0.0          0.0          0.0   
3          7         3.0  1-may          0.0          0.0          1.0   
           8         3.0  2-may          1.0          0.0          0.0   
           0         NaN    NaN          0.0          0.0          0.0   
           1         NaN    NaN          0.0          0.0          1.0   

              9.00-10.00       target  
contact_id                             
1          0         0.0   9.00-10.00  
           1         1.0   9.00-10.00  
           2         2.0  11.00-12.00  
           3         2.0  14.00-15.00  
           4         2.0  10.00-11.00  
2          5         1.0   9.00-10.00  
           6         1.0   9.00-10.00  
           0         0.0          NaN  
           1         1.0          NaN  
3          7         0.0  14.00-15.00  
           8         0.0  10.00-11.00  
           0         0.0          NaN  
           1         0.0          NaN
```

The function seems to be working for the first group i.e. `contact_id` 1 and not quite exactly for other `contact_id`. So now the questions are:

1) Why there are NaN rows getting inserted? How to get them not inserted?
2) Is this the right way to apply a function to each group? 
3) What is the correct way to apply a function to each group?

If I am missing anything please suggest me. Thanks a lot as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the solution to my question in a very non-elegant way. If someone ever needs a reference, comment down here and I'll share my solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [25]: (df.assign(col=df['answer'])
            .pivot_table(index=['contact_id','date','answer'], 
                         columns='col', aggfunc='size')
            .fillna(0)
            .reset_index())
Out[25]:
col  contact_id   date       answer  10.00-11.00  11.00-12.00  14.00-15.00  9.00-10.00
0             1  1-May   9.00-10.00          0.0          0.0          0.0         1.0
1             1  2-May   9.00-10.00          0.0          0.0          0.0         1.0
2             1  3-May  11.00-12.00          0.0          1.0          0.0         0.0
3             1  4-May  14.00-15.00          0.0          0.0          1.0         0.0
4             1  5-May  10.00-11.00          1.0          0.0          0.0         0.0
5             2  2-May   9.00-10.00          0.0          0.0          0.0         1.0
6             2  3-May   9.00-10.00          0.0          0.0          0.0         1.0
7             3  1-May  14.00-15.00          0.0          0.0          1.0         0.0
8             3  2-May  10.00-11.00          1.0          0.0          0.0         0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df.answer)],1)
Out[1272]: 
   contact_id   date       answer  10.00-11.00  11.00-12.00  14.00-15.00  9.00-10.00
0           1  1-May   9.00-10.00            0            0            0           1
1           1  2-May   9.00-10.00            0            0            0           1
2           1  3-May  11.00-12.00            0            1            0           0
3           1  4-May  14.00-15.00            0            0            1           0
4           1  5-May  10.00-11.00            1            0            0           0
5           2  2-May   9.00-10.00            0            0            0           1
6           2  3-May   9.00-10.00            0            0            0           1
7           3  1-May  14.00-15.00            0            0            1           0
8           3  2-May  10.00-11.00            1            0            0           0
```

Comment: This is clever! I didn't recognize it's a "one-hot-encoding"

Comment: @MaxU ah, your answer considered duplicated key ,I still think using pivot is more safer :-)

Comment: I think it depends on what OP really wants. After I saw your answer i'm thinking that OP wanted to do one hot encoding...

Comment: Thank you. But this just gives me the binary columns. What I want is what I have edited to highlight in bold

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal how you got the 2 ?

Comment: I want to get 2, that's what I'm asking here. I want the output that looks like the data frame under "I want the data to look like" highlighted in bold. I just don't want dummy variables.